# Android Streaming HTML URL to Player

Tags: android, streaming, vlc, android-video-player, video-player

I'm trying to make a link that's works like this mobile website:
http://m.tn.com.ar/

When I click the link `En Vivo`, it redirects me to http://m.tn.com.ar/envivo/24hs.

In PC, however, nothing happens. Instead, in Android it opens a live streaming video using Player App (I use Android VLC Player).

How can I make a link like this with HTML, JavaScript and/or PHP having the streaming URL *rtsp://stream.tn.com.ar/live/tnhd1*?

Comment: make sure this link is  working " http://m.tn.com.ar/envivo/24hs "  I click in it but I doesn't work

Comment: works in android not pc

Comment: oh OK this right then , you can check this http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.sg/2011/08/how-to-play-mp4-video-in-android-using.html

Comment: I've to paste it in <script> tag in html?

Comment: i've found it! is in the answer

Comment: but this php code , not android

Comment: I asked for mobile website, not mobile apps. Thanks mina fawzy

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// USER AGENT VAR
extract($_SERVER);
$sua = str_replace(array('.',';',':','(',')','-','_',','),array(' '),( str_replace(array('/'),array('.'),strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) ));

if(preg_match('/android/',$sua)){
    // IF ANDROID EXTERNAL APP
    header ("Location: rtsp://stream.tn.com.ar/live/tnhd1"); 
}else{
    // IF PC FLASH
    echo "Reproductor flash usando el streaming rtsp://stream.tn.com.ar/live/tnhd1";
    }
?>
```